# How to cut continuous variables in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have following dataframe in pandas

```
 ID     C1       
 1      12.23
 2      14.54
 3      9.23
 4      23.32
 5      22.21
 6      35
 7      40
```

I want to bin the `C1` in bins of 5, following is my desired dataframe

```
 ID     C1        C2     
 1      12.23     10-15
 2      14.54     10-15 
 3      9.23      5-10
 4      23.32     20-25
 5      22.21     20-25
 6      35        30-35
 7      40        35-40
```

I am using following code to bin the varible

```
bins = [0, 1, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40]
df['C2'] = pd.cut(df['C1'], bins)
```

Above code yields values such as `(9, 10],(35, 40]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use parameter `labels` created dynamically from bins with list comprehension and `f-string`s:

```
bins = [0, 1, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40]
labels = [f'{i}-{j}' for i, j in zip(bins[:-1], bins[1:])] 

df['C2'] = pd.cut(df['C1'], bins=bins, labels=labels)
print (df)
   ID     C1     C2
0   1  12.23  10-15
1   2  14.54  10-15
2   3   9.23   5-10
3   4  23.32  20-25
4   5  22.21  20-25
5   6  35.00  30-35
6   7  40.00  35-40
```

After zip by all values without last `[:-1]` with all values without first `bins[1:]` get tuples:

```
print (list(zip(bins[:-1], bins[1:])))
[(0, 1), (1, 5), (5, 10), (10, 15), (15, 20), (20, 25), (25, 30), (30, 35), (35, 40)]
```

And then join each tuple together with `f-strings` in list comprehension:

```
labels = [f'{i}-{j}' for i, j in zip(bins[:-1], bins[1:])] 
print (labels)
['0-1', '1-5', '5-10', '10-15', '15-20', '20-25', '25-30', '30-35', '35-40']
```

Comment: can you please explain me the code in the `labels` ?

Comment: @Neil - Give  me some time for explanation.

Comment: real quick question, whenever `0` is encountered its giving `nan` for those rows

Comment: @Neil - need parameter `include_lowest=True` to `cut`, check [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following, to generate 3 classes:

```
df['C2']=pd.cut(df['C1'], bins=np.linspace(np.min(df['C1']),np.max(df['C1']),4)\
, include_lowest=True, labels=list(range(0,3)))
```